# Covert String (looks like list format) into List

Tags: string, flutter, list

```
  String testing = '["Template","Data","Manual","Checklist","Others"]';
```

How to convert this string (look like list)
into the 'List-String'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is in JSON format, so you need just to decode it :

first, import the dart convert:

```
import "dart:convert";
```

then use the jsonDecode to get a list :

```
List list = jsonDecode(testing);
```

this will result a `List<dynamic>`, then you can cast it's type if you want :

```
List<String>  listOfStrings = (jsonDecode(testing) as List).map((e) => e as String).toList();
```